# Throughput capabilities of Heroku proxy server

Tags: heroku

How many requests can Heroku's "Vegur" http proxy handle for a simple "hello world" before hitting the limits (if any)? 
Will setting up nginx with ec2 micro, serving same index.html, allow more Throughput ?
Does heroku throttle the requests per dyno?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Dynos are all small processes running on EC2 machines behind the scenes. Therefore, it will almost always be more *performant* to run identical code on an EC2 server directly as opposed to Heroku, because when you're using Heroku you're sharing a server with other developers.

With that said, Heroku isn't really about having the fastest server -- it's about simplifying your entire development and deployment stack as much as possible to:

- Avoid downtime.
- Force you to architect code properly.
- Make it easier to scale your project as it grows.
- etc.